# How i can translate data-intro from inro.js to other languages using i18n in angular

Tags: html, typescript, internationalization, i18next, intro.js

I am using intro.js for showing quick start tour in angular. I am using data-intro and data-step attributes to display order and information of component that is displaying next in quick start tour.

I am not able to translate data-intro. I tried using below
Scenario 1. In HTML file,
[data-intro] ='"next step" | i18n'
data-intro ='{{"next step" | i18n"}}'
when i ran, that particular next step screen is getting hidden

scenario 2. In ts File

data_1 = this.i18n.t("next step")
when i print data_1, getting translated text.
in html file

[data-intro]="data_1"

when i ran, I am getting data_1 in that particular screen tour instead of translated text.

I tried both scenarios. But neither of them is worked.

Any help is appreciated. I am not why it is not translation.

When i try to translate using i18n, I need that particular data-inro of component need to be translated based user selected language.

Answer (score 0):

Intro code is vanilla and so rendered outside of Angular. I can only imagine without knowing your code base that intro.js is instanced pre angular template compilation completion.

Intro.js when instanced grabs the values and caches them, so I would suggest getting it to set itself up AfterViewInit.